# Converting a PKCS12 certificate to PEM certificate in .NET and vice versa?

Tags: c#, security, certificate, x509certificate2

PKCS12 certificate is stored in binary format while PEM certificate is an ASCII file which can be opened and viewed in a text editor.

Q1. How can I convert a PEM ceritificate of the form below to a PKCS12 certificate programmatically?

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
*****CERTIFICATE DATA*****
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
*****PRIVATE KEY DATA******** 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Q2. Now I have read a PKCS12 file and I want to convert the PKCS12 data into a PEM format, again using a .NET program?

Do I need to use any of the encoding schemes supported in .NET?

Note: I am using CryptoAPI library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [Mentalis.org Security Library](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/seclib/) can do this. I think they have an example that covers what you want to do; look for the Cert2PFX project in the download.

Comment: The library uses P/Invoke calls. Can I use it using CryptoAPI library